# Prevent typecasting of singleton object

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, singleton

I extended a singleton class that gets the reference to the singleton object with the following call

```
SingletonClass.singleton
```

Now I want that every time I call the `singleton` variable on my `CustomSingletonClass` that I get a reference to a `CustomSingletonClass` and not `SingletonClass`.

Right now I'm using a typecast to achieve that `((CustomSingletonClass)CustomSingletonClass.singleton)`

Do I have to override the singleton property somehow?

Comment: Is singleton a field or a property?

Comment: It would really help if you posted all of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually singleton use static properties to get the instance of the object (seems like yours is SingletonClass.singleton).

As it is a static call, you can't override this porperty in an inherited object because the call will always be done on the current type, not on the instance (overriding static is just nonsense).

You could try to change the way it works by adding a setter to your singleton and setting the desired instance before any call.

```
public class A
{
    private static A _instance;

    public static A Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new A();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
        set { _instance = value; }
    }
}

public class B : A
{

}

A.Instance = new B();
```